# Remotely delete multiple registry keys in a wildcard folder using powershell?

Tags: powershell, registry, appv

I am working on a script that will delete App-V keys stored in the registry. When a user opens an application, it creates a key within the following location:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppV\MAV\Configuration\Packages\**PackageID**\UserConfigEx\**SID**
```

The `PackageID` and the `SID` are unique each time and I want to be able to delete the `SID` subkey within each `PackageID` key.

The user will enter the SID and then I would like to use a wildcard (if possible) to navigate into each Package ID which is present.

So far I have the following:

```
#Take user input
$SID = Read-Host "Please enter users SID"
$computer = Read-Host "Please enter computer name"

#Test connection
Write-Host "Connecting to $computer"

if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Quiet -BufferSize 16 -Count 1) {

#Connect to registry and delete key
try
{
    $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey(‘LocalMachine’, $computer)
    $regKey = $reg.OpenSubKey(“HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\AppV\\MAV\\Configuration\\Packages\\*\\UserConfigEx\\$SID”,$true )

    if ($regkey.GetValue(“$SID”))
    {
        $regKey.DeleteValue(“$SID”)
        Write-Host
        Write-Host "$SID key deleted successfully" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host
        Write-Host "No keys with this SID exist." -ForegroundColor Red
    }


} catch {

    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    Write-Host "Unable to connect to $computer. Error: $($ErrorMessage)." -ForegroundColor Red 

}

} else 

    { 

    Write-Host "Unable to connect to $computer. Please ensure correct computer name / IP address has been entered correctly." -ForegroundColor Red

}
```

If I run this I receive:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:51 char:9
+     if ($regkey.GetValue(“$SID”))
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

I am using some of the script which I received help with [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49365514/query-a-single-registry-subkey-using-powershell) to remotely connect to the machine.

Comment: Note: The Unicode quotes used in the question are _not_ a problem, because PowerShell handles them just fine (treats them as their ASCII-range equivalents).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The **.NET registry API doesn't support wildcards (`*`) in key paths**.

  - As a result, the `$regKey.GetValue()` failed, because `$regKey = $reg.OpenSubKey(...)` returned `$null` due to not finding a key, and calling a method on `$null` always results in the error message quoted in the question.
- **By contrast, PowerShell's registry provider, via the `*-Item*` cmdlets, does, but you need [PowerShell remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_faq)** in order to use it remotely.

  - PowerShell remoting is enabled by default on Windows Server 2012 and above; on older OS versions you can enable it by running [`Enable-PSRemoting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting) on the target machine(s) (requires PSv3+).
  - With PowerShell remoting enabled, you need to wrap your code in an `Invoke-Command -ComputerName <name> { ... }` call (to which you may have to pass credentials too).
- If enabling PowerShell remoting is not an option, you must *emulate* wildcard-based matching via a *nested loop* based on per-element wildcard matching of the results from [`.GetSubkeyNames()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getsubkeynames).
- As an aside: you never need to escape `\` as `\\` in PowerShell strings; PowerShell uses `` ` `` as the escape character inside `"..."`, so the only character you need to escape there is `` ` `` itself, as ``` `` ```.

A PowerShell remoting-based solution:

Note that `Invoke-Command -ComputerName ...` **must be called from an *elevated* session** (`Run As Administrator`):

```
try {
  Invoke-Command -ErrorAction Stop -ComputerName $computer {

    # Define wildcard-based path.
    $keyPath = "registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppV\MAV\Configuration\Packages\*\UserConfigEx\$SID"

    # See if it matches any keys.
    if (Test-Path $keyPath) {
      # Note: I'm assuming you want to remove the entire *key*.
      #       To only remove a key's *value*, use Remove-ItemProperty.
      Remove-Item -Path $keyPath
    } else {
      Write-Warning "No keys with SID $SID exist."
    }

  }

} catch [System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException] {
  # Note: Depending on the specifics of your Invoke-Command call, the reason may
  #       be permissions-related; when in doubt, examine $_
  Write-Warning "Unable to connect to $computer. Please ensure correct computer name / IP address has been entered correctly:`n$_"
} catch {
  # Other, unexpected failure.
  Throw
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I am unable to use `Invoke-Command` in the organisation I work at as we do not have the WinRM service running - something I am currently working on getting changed.

Comment: Following on from this, the fact that it does not support wildcard paths, would this mean it will not be possible via the method I am trying and that only an invoke-command, or doing it locally on the machine would be the only options?

Comment: You can get the items at the leve where you are trying to use a wildcard then loop through them yourself.

Comment: I see re WinRM - good luck. Re doing it via .NET directly: please see my  update (which is essentially what @EBGreen recommends).

Answer (score -2):

Looks like an ascii vs unicode quotation mark issue:

You have:

```
$regkey.GetValue(“$SID”)
```

which should be replaced with:

```
$regkey.GetValue("$SID")
```

Comment: Exact same error message after amending this. I have even tried without any quotation marks and again same error.

Comment: That's not the problem, because the PowerShell parser (perhaps surprisingly) also accepts non-ASCII-range punctuation - try `[int]::Parse(“1”)`, for instance.